# Quiero hacer que mi Card no se desborde de mi div

Tags: javascript, css, html5, div

**Ya intente varias cosas y no me funciona, mis cards se salen de la pantalla inicial, intente desde html, css y javascript pero no me funciona, ya estuve checando todo y no encuentro el error**

**Ya hice muchos intentos en el css y en js**

```
.card-view-simple2{
  background-color: #323232;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.8);
  min-width: 280px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-width: 1px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
```

**son dos css los que utilizo uno para el diseño y otro para la ubicacion y cual esta llamando desde el html**

```css
.cards-container-10 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  padding: 8px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```
    </div>
    <div id="main_cards_container" class="cards-container-10">
    
 

    </div>

    <!-- Pie de página -->
    <footer id="footer" class="footer"></footer>

</body>

</html>
```

**Se supone que la barra de arriba que se ve negra es un div y donde se ve que termina ahi se deberia pasar para abajo las cards que sobran, ya intente con el felx pero no me lo agarra**

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tienes esta relacionado con la clase .main_cards_container. Al poner la propiedad "display: grid" la forma de hacer que los elementos se ajusten a tu contenedor seria a través de la propiedad "grid-template-colums" con la función repeat() como el siguiente ejemplo:

```css
.cards-container-10 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  padding: 8px;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  border: 1px solid red
} /* observamos que no es necesario el align items ni el flex-wrap */
```

O bien la otra forma, que en lo personal me gusta más, sería haciendo uso de flexbox, cambiando el "display: grid" por "display: flex" y ahora si que tendria efecto el wrap que estas haciendo en tu contenedor. Te dejo un ejemplo con flexbox

```css
.card-view-simple2 {
  background-color: #323232;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.8);
  min-width: 280px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-width: 1px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards-container-10 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="main_cards_container" class="cards-container-10">
        <div class="card-view-simple2"></div>
        <div class="card-view-simple2"></div>
        <div class="card-view-simple2"></div>
        <div class="card-view-simple2"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Pie de página -->
      <footer id="footer" class="footer"></footer>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hola, ya intente lo que me dijiste pero no hay solucion, sigue sin moverse alguna card

Comment: Okay, con gusto te ayudo si proporcionas mas a detalle el código, me parece que el html que pusiste esta recortado, quedo atento ☺️

Comment: muchas gracias, mas arriba subi el html completo

Comment: @FernandaRodriguez no se aplico la edición, me parece que hubo un problema que no aclaraba mas el problema, podrías intentar de nuevo siendo un poco mas especifica?